# Analogue of Queue.Peek() for BlockingCollection when listening to consuming IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I'm using [Pipelines pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963548.aspx) implementation to decouple messages consumer from a producer to avoid slow-consumer issue.

In case of any exception on a message processing stage `[1]` it will be lost and not dispatched to an other service/layer `[2]`. How can I handle such issue in `[3]` so message will not be lost and what is important! order of messages will not be mixed up so upper service/layer will get messages in the order they came in. I have an idea which involves an other intermediate `Queue` but it seems complex? Unfortunately `BlockingCollection<T>` does not expose any analogue of `Queue.Peek()` method so I can just read next available message and in case of successfull processing do `Dequeue()`

```
private BlockingCollection<IMessage> messagesQueue;    

// TPL Task does following:
// Listen to new messages and as soon as any comes in - process it
foreach (var cachedMessage in 
             messagesQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable(cancellation))
{    
    const int maxRetries = 3;
    int retriesCounter = 0;
    bool isSent = false;

    // On this point a message already is removed from messagesQueue
    while (!isSent && retriesCounter++ <= maxRetries)
    {
        try
        {
           // [1] Preprocess a message
           // [2] Dispatch to an other service/layer    
           clientProxyCallback.SendMessage(cachedMessage);
           isSent = true;
        }                                
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
           // [3]   
           // logging
           if (!isSent && retriesCounter < maxRetries)
           {
              Thread.Sleep(NSeconds);
           }
        }            
    
        if (!isSent && retriesCounter == maxRetries)
        {
           // just log, message is lost on this stage!
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Forgot to say this is IIS hosted WCF service which dispatches messages back to Silverlight client WCF Proxy via client callback contract.

**EDIT2:** Below is how I would do this using `Peek()`, Am I missing something?

```
bool successfullySent = true;
try
{
   var item = queue.Peek();
   PreProcessItem(item);
   SendItem(item);       
}
catch(Exception exception)
{
   successfullySent = false;
}
finally
{
   if (successfullySent)
   {
       // just remove already sent item from the queue
       queue.Dequeue();
   }
}
```

**EDIT3:** Surely I can use old style approach using while loop, bool flag, `Queue` and `AutoResetEvent`, but I just wondering whether the same is possible using `BlockingCollection` and  `GetConsumingEnumerable()` I think facility like `Peek` would be
very helpful when using together with consuming enumerable, since otherwise all Pipeline pattern implementation examples new stuff like `BlockingCollection` and `GetConsumingEnumerable()` looks not durable and I have to move back to the old approach.

Comment: Do you expect the exception not to be thrown when you try again? If yes, just put a while loop until no exception is thrown. If no, you need to decide what to do in the case an item cannot be processed. Maybe pass an error message to the next layer?

Comment: This is server WCF service whcih dispatch message to a client proxy, it can be that connection if failed and in 5 seconds client will reconnect to a service and ready to receive a messages, `while` loop is what I'm doing now with N resend retries, I must mention this, but there is always question whcih magic number for reconectRetries and timeout to choose

Comment: It sounds like you're on the way to reinvent message queues. Have you considered using something like MSMQ or RabbitMQ?

Comment: @dtb: This is a heavy technology, Im not sure this is the best way to go for WCF service?! but must admit it is most robust and reliable

Comment: @sll And why do you think that using something like `Peek()` would help you avoid those magic numbers?

Comment: done editing http://stackoverflow.com/a/13583279/659190

Comment: @sll That means that if there is some permanent failure, you're never going to progress past that item. If that's what you want, you can just use infinite number of retries, you don't need `Peek()` for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should consider intermediate queue.

`BlockingCollection<T>` can't "peek" items because of its nature - there can be more than one consumer. One of them can *peek* an item, and another one can *take* it - hence, the first one will try to take item, that already has been taken.

Comment: If there is only a single client, peeking can be done with the `First()` extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`, which doesn't remove an item from the blocking collection.

Comment: @pvoosten - thanks for that. It 'feels' dangerous to implement it like this though, since these kind of assumptions often prove to be  false at a later date when the architecture is hard to undo. But if people *know* there's only one consumer, then it looks a great way of doing it.

Comment: @pvoosten : `First()` will throw an exception if there is nothing in the collection. What if you want to block until there is at least one item in the collection (like `Take()` but without removing the element).

Comment: @tigrou: then just follow the answer, and consider an intermediate queue. Checking for items in the collection will otherwise always either introduce a race condition or the need for locking.

Answer (score 4):

As [Dennis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13582679/659190) says in his comment, [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) provides a blocking wrapper to any implementor of the [`IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287147.aspx) interface.

As you can see, `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`, by design, does not define a `Peek<T>` or other methods necessary to implement one. This means that `BlockingCollection<T>` cannot, as it stands, offer an analouge to `Peek`.

If you consider, this greately reduces the concurrencey problems created by the utility trade off of a `Peek` implementation. How can you consume without consuming? To `Peek` concurrently you would have to lock the head of the collection until the `Peek` operation was completed which I and the designers of `BlockingCollection<T>` view as sub-optimal. I think it would also be messy and difficult to implement, requiring some sort of disposable peek context.

If you consume a message and its consumption fails you will have to handle with it. You could add it to another failures queue, re-add it to the normal processing queue for a furture retry or just log its failure for posterity or, some other action appropriate to your context.

If you don't want to consume the messages concurrently then there is no need to use `BlockingCollection<T>` since you don't need concurrent consumption. You could use [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) directly, you'll still get synchronicity off adds, and you can use [`TryPeek<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267308.aspx) safely since you control a single consumer. If consumption fails you could stop consumption with a infinite retry loop in you desire although, I suggest this requires some design thought.

Comment: I believe the `BlockingCollection` adds one more potential benefit, namely that `TryTake()` will wait until an item is available. If we want to keep the `BlockingCollection` because of that, we can still peek using `Any()`, correct? (Under the assumption of a single consuming thread.)

Answer (score 4):

`BlockingCollection<T>` is a wrapper around `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`, which is more generic than e.g. `ConcurrentQueue` and gives the implementer the freedom of not having to implement a `(Try)Peek` method.

However, you can always call `TryPeek` on the underlying queue directly:

```
ConcurrentQueue<T> useOnlyForPeeking = new ConcurrentQueue<T>();
BlockingCollection<T> blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<T>(useOnlyForPeeking);
...
useOnlyForPeeking.TryPeek(...)
```

Note however that **you must not modify your queue via `useOnlyForPeeking`**, otherwise `blockingCollection` will get confused and may [throw `InvalidOperationException`s](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/R/6b00be0930a56743.html) at you, but I'd be surprised if calling the non-modifying `TryPeek` on this concurrent data structure would be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)** instead, it has [`TryDequeue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287208%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method.

> `ConcurrentQueue<T>.TryDequeue(out T result)` tries to **remove and return the object** at the beginning of the concurrent queue, it returns **true if an element was removed and returned** from the beginning of the ConcurrentQueue successfully.

So, no need to check a Peek first.

`TryDequeue()` is thread safe:

> `ConcurrentQueue<T>` **handles all synchronization internally**. If two threads call TryDequeue(T) at precisely the same moment, neither operation is blocked.

As far as I understand **it returns false only if the queue is empty**:

> If the queue was populated with code such as q.Enqueue("a"); q.Enqueue("b"); q.Enqueue("c"); and two threads concurrently try to dequeue an element, one thread will dequeue a and the other thread will dequeue b. Both calls to TryDequeue(T) will return true, because they were both able to dequeue an element. If each thread goes back to dequeue an additional element, one of the threads will dequeue c and return true, whereas the other thread will find the queue empty and will return false.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287208%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

**UPDATE**

Perhaps, the easiest option would be using [`TaskScheduler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Class. With it you can wrap all your processing tasks into the queue's items and simplify the implementation of synchronisation.

Comment: `BlockingCollection<T>` is a wrapper around `ConcurrentQueue<T>` by default. There's a difference between them: `BlockingCollection<T>` allows to wait until there will be available items in the queue, whereas `ConcurrentQueue<T>` hasn't this functionality.

Comment: Ok `TryDequeue()` just allows checking whether an item was dequeued, it is like `Int32.TryParse()` - does work without an exception in case of failure

Comment: @sll It doesn't only check, it actually removes (dequeues) the element: `"Tries to remove and return the object at the beginning of the concurrent queue."` It returns false only if the queue is empty.

Comment: Sure, it does check and remove, so it deffers from standard `Queue.Dequeue()`: it does not throw `InvalidOperationException` if queue is empty and just return false, nothing more. So how would you recommend using it in my case? Especially listenign to queue? I do not like `while(queue.TryDequeue(), tiemOut)` loop

Comment: @sll Sorry, maybe I misunderstood the problem, I thought it was only about `Peek()` method. You surely need some additional synchronization object; I would use some event, ManualResetEvent maybe...

Comment: I think you are missing a point of my question, basically there is nothing about multiple threads dequeueing items, the problem is when an item dequeued and service failed to send it to an other service - item is mostly lost because it is already out of an queue and not sent to a target service so in case of any failure in this moment of time an item will be lost. Using Queue I can Peek item, send it, and if sent successfully - dequeue it, otherwise leave in queue since Peek does not remove it.