# What is the use case of ConcurrentQueue<T>.TryPeek()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

Inspired by my current problem, which is kind of identical to this:
[Analogue of Queue.Peek() for BlockingCollection when listening to consuming IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13581945/2477582) with the difference that I - currently - am using `ConcurrentQueue<T>` instead of `BlockingCollection<T>`, I wonder what any use case for `ConcurrentQueue<T>.TryPeek()` may be?

Of course I mean a use case without manual `lock(myQueue)` stuff to serialize queue accesses as TPL is meant to improve/substitute those lockings.

Comment: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c20229/Working-with-Concurrent-Collections-in-NET-Framework-40.htm this article it may help you.

Comment: Sorry but in this article is nothing relevant to the actual question. Serendipitously interesting was the description of TryPeek() and TryTake() of ConcurrentBag - but this is a different type than ConcurrentQueue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had an application that used `ConcurrentQueue<T>.TryPeek` to good effect. One thread was set up to monitor the queue. Mostly it was looking at queue size, but we also wanted to get an idea of latency. Because the items in the queue had a time stamp field that said what time they were put into the queue, my monitoring thread could call `TryPeek` to get the item at the head of the queue, subtract the insertion time from the current time, and tell me how long the item had been in the queue. Over time and many samples, that gave me a very clear picture of how long it was taking for a received item to be processed.

It didn't matter that some other thread might dequeue the item while my monitoring code was still examining it.

I can think of a few other scenarios in which it would be useful to see what's at the head of the queue, even though it might be pulled off immediately.

Comment: Yeey, appreciating this approach - this makes sense in a completely different way I thought of. And I expected this kind of different type of use case I possibly never discovered on my own (which is why I asked this question here). One additional question: how did you measured queue size?

Comment: @Nicolas: Queue size is given by the `Count` property.

Comment: Yes, ok. I just asked because I implemented an approximate memory limit - approximate because I did not found a way to measure the in-memory size of a queue without external tools. Now I count the binary serialized size of each element while en-/dequeuing -.- and I was curious on alternative methods; but I expected the normal count of items as answer... :)

Answer (score 2):

I have a `ConcurrentQueue` where many threads may `Enqueue`, but I limit just one thread doing `TryPeek` and `TryDequeue` by `lock`:

```
lock (dequeueLock)
    if (queue.TryPeek(out item))
        if (item.Value <= threshold)
            queue.TryDequeue(out item);
```

*Note:* other threads may continue to `Enqueue` while this code runs.

It would be nicer to have some atomic peek - check - dequeue operation, but the `lock` is fine for my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

`TryPeek` is used to wait for the object to be at the first of the queue. `TryDequeue` will dequeue any object that is there. So, for instance, I wrote a webserver that is multithreaded, but during authorization, when authorization is enabled for certain request, they need at one point to be processed in the order they were received. I don't want to lock up the whole thread function or half of it, only so that for some clients I can process their requests in order.

So, I created a `Dictionary<string, ConcurrentQueue<HttpListenerContext>>`, then at the very beginning of the server thread, I lock temporarily and check to see if authorization will be required, if so I store the `HttpListenerContext` in a queue with the client IP as the dictionary key, so that different clients don't block each other's threads unnecessarily. Then, I process the headers and compute the hashes as normal, as page may make two or three request using ajax and websockets connections after the initial, it is better to multithread the hashing of the authorization information (which is digest authorization I implemented for HttpListener myself, so that I am not restricted to using Active Directory). Then when the authorization needs to be checked for the case that what is called the client nonce count is only one greater than the last request for that client's session, a security feature, I use the que I created and `TryPeek` with `Thread.Yield()` to wait until that threads `HttpListenerContext` is the first in the que to finish authorization and then dequeue it.

In short, it can be used to multithread where for most the thread you want things to run in parallel, to take advantage of different cores, but then for some threads for a piece of them you need everything to get back in order.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you use this method when you want to do a peek but you are not sure there is an item in the queue. Normally Peek on an empty queue will throw an exception. TryPeek will return false if the item is not there. This can be extremely useful in multithreaded scenarios where another thread may dequeue the item in between checks for empty queue and actually peeking for the value.

Comment: Actually TryDequeue() does this check and this is extremely cool. But TryPeek() giving me an object of `ConcurrentQueue<T>` is of no use in my eyes, because a different thread could have had dequeued the same object in parallel.

Comment: What do you mean? TryPeek returns T not ConcurrentQueue<T>. Do you ask for a case where one would Peek but not Dequeue in general (no matter if it is multithreaded scenario)?

Comment: Sorry this was not expressed clearly, I meant: "But TryPeek() giving me an object OUT of `ConcurrentQueue<T>` ..." (which of course is of type T) - but in which scenario I would use this object now? I can not safely use it, because it is in danger of being dequeued in parallel by a different thread. Remind: I don't have an actual problem with TryPeek() - I just stumpled across it with no idea for when anyone may ever have a use of it, respecting the described circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
T item = bc.GetConsumingEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
if (item != null)
{
 //...
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how this answers the question?

Comment: Wraping a ConcurrentQueue<T> in BlockingCollection<T> allows you to enumeration non-blocking mode and non-blocking search ie: var bc = new    BlockingCollection<T>(new ConcurrentQueue<T>()); Other threads at the same time continue to enqueue bc.TryAdd(newItem) and dequeue bc.TryTake(out removedItem) from the queue

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at an object to see if it is valid before taking it out is an option, just remember that when you do this that the Concurrent Queue will create a reference and not release the object from memory when you dequeue it. If you do, and you are memory profiling as I did with my ConcurrentQueue, you will see something like this.

[image]

Notice the ConcurrentQueueSegment with 11,060 instances while the queue only holds 8.